# Apache can't access from wan on archlinux

Tags: nat, httpd, apache-2.4, vmware-workstation, arch-linux

Information:

- Archlinux via vmware
- Have ports 8080, 443 and 80 forwarded to the local ip from router running pfsense
- I can access the webpage from lan via local ip.

My httpd.conf:

```
Listen 80
ServerAdmin: webmaster@mywebsite.com
Servername: mywebsite.com
```

My iptables.rules: (Replace wanip with my wan ip)

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Mar 14 08:15:17 2015
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1941:153776]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [149:19536]
-A INPUT -d wanip/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d wanip/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d wanip/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d wanip/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s wanip/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s wanip/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s wanip/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 443 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s wanip/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s wanip/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sat 14 08:15:17 2015
```

I can access by ftp, and ssh from wan.

I use virtual hosts for subdomains. (I need to have them for subdomains in the future.)

```
 <VirtualHost *:80> 
 ServerAdmin webmaster@mysubdomain.mywebsite.com
 ServerName mysubdomain.mywebsite.com
 ServerAlias www.mysubdomain.mywebsite.com
 DocumentRoot /srv/http/mysubdomain.mywebsite.com/public_html/
 ErrorLog /srv/http/mysubdomain.mywebsite.com/logs/error.log 
 CustomLog /srv/http/mysubdomain.mywebsite.com/logs/access.log combined
        <Directory />
           Order deny,allow
           Allow from all
        </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

I tried adding a entry to my hosts file

```
192.168.1.201 mysubdomain.mydomain.com localhost
```

Any ideas on how to get it connect to it from the address? I'm at a loss here. I also apologise for the mysubdomain.mydomain.com replacement. I am currently fixing the network and there's more security holes and id rather not post the address.

I assure you that I own the domain and the subdomain and the dns records are pointed at the correct ip addresses.

Dump of httpd -S:

```
[deathmock@archweb ~]$ httpd -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   mysubdomain.mydomain.com (/etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:23)
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/srv/http"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/httpd/error_log"
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/run/httpd/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="http" id=33 not_used
Group: name="http" id=33 not_used
```

Comment: you need to configure a nat roule {wan ip:80 } > { localip:80 } if your wan ip is come from your  pfsense router, you need to do the nat roule there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was another program on my network that was hogging my port 80 on another system. Figured it out after tracking the connection.